# USB Serial ports reset each time the system is restarted How to prevent that?

Tags: usb, serial-port

I am using `Ubuntu 18:04 LTS` and am trying to communicate with the serial ports but each time I restart the system the ports are reset is there a way to prevent the same. ie assuming I am using a ultrasonic sensor which is assigned to `/dev/ttyUSB0` and am using a pulse rate sensor which is assigned to `/dev/ttyUSB1` then the ports shall be stable till the system is restarted after which the port often tend to change, so is there a way to freeze the ports assigned to sensors to ensure that they remain unchanged even after the restart.
There can be any number of sensors connected to the system.

Comment: have you tried adding an entry into /etc/fstab/ ?

Comment: No, How to do that  ?

Answer (score 0):

Once I had the same problem on a beagle bone with debian jessie and later stretch.

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/66901/how-to-bind-usb-device-under-a-static-name

That helped me out.

In summary they suggested to add udev rules:

Quote of what helped me:

> The rule syntax above may work on some distributions, but did not work on mine (Raspbian). Since I never found a single document that explains all the ins and outs, I wrote my own, to be found here. This is what it boils down to.
>
> 1. find out what's on ttyUSB:
>
>    dmesg | grep ttyUSB
> 2. list all attributes of the device:
>
>    udevadm info --name=/dev/ttyUSBx --attribute-walk
>
> (with your device number(s) instead of x, of course). Pick out a unique identifier set, eg idVendor + idProduct. You may also need SerialNumber if you have more than one device with the same idVendor and idProduct. SerialNumbers ought to be unique for each device.
>
> 3. Create a file /etc/udev/rules.d/99-usb-serial.rules with something like this line >in it:
>
>    SUBSYSTEM=="tty", ATTRS{idVendor}=="1234", ATTRS{idProduct}=="5678", SYMLINK+="your_device_name"
>
> (assuming you don't need a serial number there, and of course with the numbers for idVendor and idProduct that you found in step 2.
>
> 4. Load the new rule:
>
>    sudo udevadm trigger
> 5. Verify what happened:
>
>    ls -l /dev/your_device_name
>
> will show what ttyUSB number the symlink went to. If it's /dev/ttyUSB1, then verify who owns that and to which group it belongs:
>
> ls -l /dev/ttyUSB1
>
> Then just for the fun of it:
>
> udevadm test -a -p  $(udevadm info -q path -n /dev/your_device_name)